# Nightmare.js does not work with Azure webjob

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-webjobs, nightmare

I am trying to run an azure webjob which takes a json object and renders a webpage, then prints it to pdf, via the electron browser in Nightmare.js.

When I run this locally it works perfectly, but when I run it in azure webjob it never completes.
I get the two `console.log` statements output to the log, but seeing as I can not output anything from the nightmare.js calls, nor display the electron browser window, I have no idea what is going wrong.

There is also a webserver in the script, omitted as it seems to take the request with the json object and pass it to `createPage` just fine.

I have verified that index.html file is in the right directory. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare'),
    http = require('http');

function createPage(o, final) {

    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var page = Nightmare({
        //show: true, //uncomment to show electron browser window
        //openDevTools: { mode: 'detach'}, //uncomment to open developer console ('show: true' needs to be set)
        gotoTimeout: 300000, //set timeout for .goto() to 2 minutes
        waitTimeout: 300000, //set timeout for .wait() to 5 minutes
        executionTimeout: 600000 //set timeout for .evaluate() to 10 minutes
    })
    .goto('file:\\\\' + __dirname + '\\index.html');

    page.wait("#ext-quicktips-tip") //wait till HTML is loaded
    .wait(function () { // wait till JS is loaded
        console.log('Extjs loaded.');
        return !!(Ext.isReady && window.App && App.app);
    });

    console.log("CreatePage()1");

    page.evaluate(function (template, form, lists, printOptions) {
        App.pdf.Builder.create({
            template: template,
            form: form,
            lists: lists,
            format: o.printOptions.format,
        });
        console.log('Create done');
    }, template, form, o.lists, printOptions);

    console.log("CreatePage()2");
    page.wait(function () {
        console.log('Content created. ' + App.pdf.Builder.ready);
        return App.pdf.Builder.ready;
    })
    .pdf(o.outputDir + form.filename, { "pageSize": "A4", "marginsType": 1 })
    .end()
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Pdf printed, time: ' + (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000 + ' seconds');
        final(true);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Print Error: ' + err.message);
    });
}
```

## **Solved**

As Rick states in his answer, this will not currently work! 
This document lists the current state of webjobs sandbox:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox
It has the following paragraph relating to my issue:

> **PDF generation from HTML**
>
> There are multiple libraries used to convert HTML to PDF. Many Windows/.NET specific versions leverage IE APIs and therefore leverage User32/GDI32 extensively. These APIs are largely blocked in the sandbox (regardless of plan) and therefore these frameworks do not work in the sandbox.
>
> There are some frameworks that do not leverage User32/GDI32 extensively (wkhtmltopdf, for example) and we are working on enabling these in Basic+ the same way we enabled SQL Reporting.

Comment: Which type of [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) are you using? on demand, continuously, or on a schedule?

Comment: I am using continuously as I am running a http webserver in the script too.

Comment: Where is the function `createPage` called?

Comment: It is called from the http server.
When it receives a POST request it calls `createPage` with a json object `o` and a callback `final`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess for nightmare.js to work you need desktop interaction, which you're not getting on a WebJob.

Taken from [this issue](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/744) on Github:

> Nightmare isn't truly headless: it requires an Electron instance to
>   work, which in turn requires a framebuffer to render properly (at
>   least, for now).

This will not fly on an Azure WebJob.

Comment: Thanks a lot, made me search for the right keywords

Comment: Hi, I have an API that uses Nightmare for web scrapping and tests are failing during Azure CI... have you found a way to make this work?