# Launch of Nightmare.js on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, nightmare

I use Nightmare on my local server, it works. I tried to launch this project on MS Azure. I don't see any errors and warnings in logs. But code running stops during the first use of Nightmare.

I found out that Azure doesn't support Electron. [Nightmare.js does not work with Azure webjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037918/nightmare-js-does-not-work-with-azure-webjob)

Is there a possibility to run my code on Azure?
If there isn't, please advise me the hosting where Nightmare will work.

**UPDATE**

I use Azure Web Apps on Windows. I followed the advice of @evilSnobu and restart my server on Azure Web Apps on Linux. But it not worked too.

Such I see in log, it work, while not meet Nidthmare. After that I see this lines in log (balnk14 - its my project):

```
 2017-08-14 09:57:45.434 ERROR - Container logs STDERR>> 
2017-08-14T09:53:58.254134911Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2017-08-14T09:53:58.254164596Z npm info using npm@3.10.10
2017-08-14T09:53:58.254167894Z npm info using node@v6.9.3
2017-08-14T09:54:00.107284364Z npm info lifecycle blank5@1.0.0~prestart: blank5@1.0.0
2017-08-14T09:54:00.127148759Z npm info lifecycle blank5@1.0.0~start: blank5@1.0.0
2017-08-14 09:57:45.449 ERROR - Container blank14_0 for site blank14 did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.0792133 sec
```

Have any idea, how to solve my problem? 
maybe the problem in my code? But it work local...

In some place I read, that I need use Xvfb. How can I use it in Azure?

Comment: Yeah, you're hitting the sandbox GDI or port binding limits, but it could work on Web Apps on Linux. Give it a shot. Else, Cloud Services or a good old IaaS VM.

Comment: @evilSnobu, thank you for your answer. I use your advice. But aproblen not solver(

Comment: Hmm, is that docker container booting up and behaving as expected if you run it on your computer? Did you bring your own container or just deployed on top of the Node.js built-in one?

Comment: On local mashine I use windows+nodejs+npm.
On azure I use Built-in container. ( http://prntscr.com/g8oq4f ). (Until this point I did not know what the Docker means)

Comment: Try to build a Docker container that contains your app and works locally, should work in App Service Linux just as well.

Comment: Hello! I chose another way.  A bought VPS on ubuntu, download  xvfb, and start node on: xvfb-run -a node index.js.   It's work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Azure is killing your container as it thinks it's not responding.

Check your Dockerfile for exposed ports. Also setting explicit WEBSITES_PORT in your Azure Web App's "Application Settings" should help.

Look from the logs how Azure is running the container  (docker run ...). It may give additional clues what is going wrong.

More detailed info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#NoPing